# Criar arquivo de áudio, a partir de URL

Tags: node.js, facebook-javascript-sdk

Preciso do arquivo de áudio do messenger, para usar na api Google Cloud Speech API. Quando um áudio é recebido no messenger, é gerada uma url que faz download de desse arquivo em .mp4. Como eu posso  a partir dessa url recuperar o áudio, e usar na API Google?

Comment: Em node ainda estou pesquisando, mas em Java tive que implementar em um projeto algo similar. Para simples tive que abrir apenas uma InputStream recebendo um Objeto URL e chamando o metodo openStream(),

`InputStream input = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com/a.txt").openStream();`

Comment: Encontrei um blog com uma postagem interessante sobre:

[link]https://subvisual.co/blog/posts/39-tutorial-html-audio-capture-streaming-to-node-js-no-browser-extensions[link]

Answer (score 1):

O truque aqui é pegar em streams, com o modulo http (ou equivalente) fazer download do ficheiro de audio e depois pipe para um stream, e aí fazer o que quiser.. Neste exemplo, guardar num ficheiro:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var audioUrl = "http://www.exemplo/audio.mp4",
    fileName = "audio.mp4";

var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
var request = http.get(audioUrl, function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```